# Flutter modal bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was experimenting with flutter modal bottom sheet. I have used a texfield in modal bottom sheet. The textfield works but somehow I am unable to see in the screen what I am currently typing.What is the way to solve it? I have included the code as well. Thanks for your response.

Here is the code:

```
    modalSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
        ),
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                    child: Center(child: Text('Testing modal sheet'))),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Hexcolor('#E9F1FE'),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                          child: Center(
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
                                hintText: 'Write a comment...',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Colors.grey),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Pressed');
                        },
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Hexcolor('#0565ac'),
                          maxRadius: 20,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_upward,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Here are the images for clarity:

[image: Texfield widget in modal sheet] [image: Keypad Hiding the typed texts]

Comment: You can try wrapping the entire content of bottom sheet with 
SingleChildScrollView and again wrapping SingleChildScrollView with Expanded widget.

Comment: @LaxmikanthMadhyastha Thanks for the response but an exception occurred.

`The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a
RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically,
Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a _InkFeatures widget.
`

Comment: try reverting  the above changes and add a Scaffold to your bottomSheet and there set  `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true`

Comment: @LaxmikanthMadhyastha It works but sadly modal sheet takes the entire screen size while I have set the sheet size to 90% of screensize through mediaquery. Thanks again!

Comment: can you paste the bottom sheet code?

Comment: @LaxmikanthMadhyastha Well, there it is. I have updated the question.